# Adding slick carousel to Magento 2 homepage

Tags: magento2, php, jquery

I'm having an issue with what I think should be a basic thing but I'm obviously doing something wrong, all I want to do is have a basic banner slider using slick slider jquery plugin. I have a custom theme working fine and I've downloaded the slick.min.js to app/design/frontend/Pyxis/pyxistheme/web/js/slick.min.js

I have then created the requirejs-config.js in my /web folder and added this:

```
    `var config = {
        paths: {
            slick:        'js/slick.min'
        },
        shim: {
            slick: {
                deps: ['jquery']
            }
        }
    };

`
```

which when I view the page source and view the file I can see that code.

My issue is that when I add the jquery code to a CMS page ie homepage like so:

```
<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'slick.min'
    ], function ($) {
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery(".home-banners").slick({
                dots: true,
                infinite: true,
                arrows: true,
                speed: 300,
                slidesToShow: 1,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I get a console error saying slick.min.js cannot be found? I have ran these commands in my terminal:

**php bin/magento setup:upgrade**
**php -d memory_limit=2048M bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB -f**
**php -d memory_limit=2048M bin/magento cache:flush**

Any idea why it can't find my slick.min.js file?

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

In your require script you need to use the path you defined in requirejs-config.js, in your case this is 'slick'.

Try updating that and then redeploying your static content (unless you're in developer mode and then you shouldn't need to).